# Get Facebook Posts on Timeline using Koala gem

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala-gem

I am trying to get all the posts on my facebook profile using Koala. I am using the following method -

> feed = graph.get_connections("me", "feed")

But this method returns an array of hash whose element is  -

> {"updated_time"=>"some time", "is_hidden"=>false, "story"=>"someone
>   and 10 others wrote on your timeline.", "from"=>{"id"=>"some id",
>   "name"=>"some name"}, "id"=>"some id", "privacy"=>{"deny"=>"",
>   "value"=>"", "friends"=>"", "description"=>"", "allow"=>""},
>   "type"=>"status", "created_time"=>"some time",
>   "status_type"=>"wall_post"}

The problem in this case is I am not able to retrieve individual posts on timeline.

There is "**story**" present in the hash but no "**Message**". I expected that there would be 11 elements in the array as 11 friends posted on timeline.

Is there any other method from which I can retrieve? Also, this is plain ruby program without any rails integration.

Thanks!

Comment: What permissions are you using with your access token to get this information?

Comment: I have given read_stream permission. I am just reading the post.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 'get_connections', do:

```
graph.get_object("me/feed?fields=message")
```

to get the messages in your feed.